# Attach bpftrace probe to C++ function

Tags: c++, trace, bpf, ebpf

I have a question about `bpftrace` syntax and hoping that someone might have seen this before.

In looking at the [bpftrace](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/master/docs/reference_guide.md#3-uprobeuretprobe-dynamic-tracing-user-level) reference document, I've been able to trace a user-app function successfully. No problems there. What I can't figure out is **how to attach a probe to a C++ method**.

For example, here is the syntax that I'm using and the error:

```
$ bpftrace -e 'uretprobe:/usr/share/BigApp:BigApp::MethodName { printf("method return\n"); }'
1.34-35: syntax error, unexpected path, expecting {
```

What would be the proper syntax for attaching a bpftrace probe to a C++ user-app?

Answer (score 3):

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class BigApp {
  public:
    void methodName() {
      std::cout << "method Name!";
    }
};

int main() {
  BigApp bigApp;      
  bigApp.methodName();      
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
g++ main.cpp -o main

# locate mangled symbol name
readelf -Ws /home/koxt/dev/cpp/main | grep methodName
69: 00000000004007ee    30 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   14 _ZN6BigApp10methodNameEv

bpftrace -e 'uprobe:/home/koxt/dev/cpp/main:_ZN6BigApp10methodNameEv { printf("1"); }'
```

Answer (score 0):

bpftrace currently support probe c++ name without demangle, like

```cpp
uprobe:executable:"function signature" {
   //...
}
```

see https://github.com/caringi/bpftrace/commit/e28ad2ca4276e1433e293dcc0346545fc316fae5